# Differentiate b/w fscanf and load function in matlab

Tags: matlab

In my matlab program i am reading the data file using fscanf and writing the the code code to read all the values.That makes me write several steps.

How to use Load() function to overcome this ad make it simple.

Answer (score 1):

So the way load works is to load variables from MATLAB binary/ascii files. In order to create said files you'll have to use the save function e.g.

```
octave:3> T = "Hello"
T = Hello
octave:4> save "-binary" "testfile" T
octave:5> clear
octave:6> T
error: 'T' undefined near line 1 column 1
octave:6> load "-binary" "testfile" T
octave:7> T
T = Hello
octave:8>
```

Sorry I used octave for the example but it's the same code either way. So if you know your going to be using the same data just save it in a MATLAB's binary format. It should save your self the time of having to use `fscanf` on it next time your playing around with the data.

Comment: +1 - This is correct for either platform - MATLAB or Octave